# UIView.animate not working in testflight - Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

I have a UIView animating like this:

```
func animateStart() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        self.firstImg.image = UIImage(named:"image.JPG")
        self.firstImg.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            self.animateSecond()
        }
    })
}

func animateSecond() {        
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.firstLbl.text = "This..."
        self.firstLbl.alpha = 1            
        self.firstLbl.alpha = 0            
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            self.animateThird()
        }
    })

}
```

It works flawlessly in simulator, and when built to a local device. However, I published my build to testflight this morning, and only the first 3 frames of the UIView animate, then the final frame animates. (I have a total of 9). The Label continues to animate as expected. I know they updated testflight yesterday... anyone experiencing anything like this after the update?

Comment: In your development environment, delete your app from your simulators and devices. Do a clean build and run the app again. Does it still work as expected or does it now work incorrectly like in Test Flight?

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it still works in simulator, but not on device after rebuilding... back to the drawing board.. eh kinda literally lol.

Comment: Device file systems are case-sensitive. The simulators usually are not. Make sure your image filenames exactly match (including case) what you have in code.

Comment: This is actually the 6th build, all previous iterations worked as intended. I did have problems with case matching initially, but resolved that in the 2nd build. The only thing I updated in this iteration are button images. None of the ones I added are affected by, or affecting any of the animation layers. That's why I wanted to blame testflight initially.      

And now I eat my words... I guess I missed a couple... or 6 that didn't match and for some reason the devices didn't care until now. Thanks a ton for the help

Comment: **Always** does a delete and clean build followed by a clean install and test before submitting an app to Apple. Things get left behind during development that might not exist when a user does a clean install.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first app I'm intending to publish, and I appreciate the advice. I do have a device outside of my dev environment I've been testing on as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was @rmaddy answer but I think it should be approved as the correct answer because I had a similar problem and cleaning out my device showed me the difference.

> In your development environment, delete your app from your simulators and devices. Do a clean build and run the app again. Does it still work as expected or does it now work incorrectly like in Test Flight?
>
> Always does a delete and clean build followed by a clean install and test before submitting an app to Apple. Things get left behind during development that might not exist when a user does a clean install